# Which data structure in C allow me to store lines and append lines easily?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I got a list of string data. 10,20,30 are the line numbers

```
10. string 1
20. string 2
30. string 3
```

and if user types in "23 string data". 23 is the line number user wants to insert into. The data should become like that

```
10. string 1
20. string 2
23. string data
30. string 3
```

and if user types in "40 string data". The data should become like that

```
10. string 1
20. string 2
23. string data
30. string 3
40. string data
```

I'm relatively new in C's data structure. **Which data structure should I use to store this kind of data efficiently**? My current direction is to implement dynamic array or linked list. However, below are the list of problems I experienced.

**Problem with dynamic array:**

1. Using the line number as the index and create sufficient space to
       ensure array length is always more or equal to the highest line
       number. Waste a lot of memory for un-used index.
2. Printing out the data would be an issue.
   Eg. index 0-9 doesn't have memory allocated. Accessing it will cause an error. Need to find ways to know which index are used?

**Problem with linked list:**

1. I cannot jump index(not sure). How do identify which line comes after
   another and insert line in between easily?

Comment: Computing is about tradeoffs. In your case you need to decide what you want to tradeoff - memory vs speed. Only you can answer that based on your full requirements. In addition to straight arrays and linked lists you may also want to look into hash tables.

Comment: You can use almost any structure you choose.  You can't index into arrays using the 'line number' since they're not uniformly spaced.  That means you'll be doing a linear search — and linked lists are arguably better (at least, inserting a new line in the middle involves less data movement).  You've got all the information you need in the current node and the next node of a list to tell whether the new line goes in between those two, and you can then do the insertion easily.

Comment: @kaylum: a hash allows you to find if a particular line number is present or not, but finding the next number after, say, 20 is rather hard with the average hash, is it not?

Comment: Hash table is the standard way to do this. An easier way: You can use a linked list with an auxiliary array containing reference pointers to every k-th slot in the string array so you have to iterate at most (k-1) indexes to find the one you want. @JonathanLeffler Is finding the next one required? If so, my second suggestion makes that easy.

Comment: @sudo: I disagree with your assessment.  For a structure that must be searched linearly, hash tables are the wrong data structure.  Given that one of the problems with a linked list is the inability to 'jump index' and the mention of lines coming after each other, I think the sequencing is important.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right. But it's not clear that the OP really needs to have ordering or how important that part is. I know the OP did show the data that way but it may be as a result of the structures the OP has in mind. But it may be that the OP is really interested in storing and fetching data quickly without necessarily needing a linear traversal. Anyway, just one more idea for the OP to consider. This question really isn't answerable in the SO format.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right. I missed the part in the OP about finding the next one. In that case, you can still use the hash table as long as you keep in each entry a pointer to the next value.

Comment: @sudo: a 'skip list' would be a nice refinement if the list was large enough to warrant it (probably not required for 20 lines; probably helpful for 1000 lines; and there'd be a break-even point somewhere in between).  The description is reminiscent of line numbers in (gasp) BASIC.

Comment: Haha, so now we know what this is for ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give the two solutions I could come up with, but this question is possibly open-ended.

1. Use a hash table. Keys are line numbers. Values are `(string, pointer to next line's value)`. This makes both random and linear access fast. **Edit:** Insertion is still `O(n)` with this. It'll only help with access time, which will be `O(1)`. The second solution has `O(1)` insertion.
2. Assuming you don't have wildly spaced out line numbers: Use a singly linked list `L` to store strings. Also create a separate array `P` containing a pointer to every `k`-th node in the list. To access line `i`, check `P[floor(i/k)]`, jump to the node it points to in `L`, and jump forward `i mod k` times to reach your string. Access time is therefore `O(k)`. Insertion time is `O(1)`. Space usage for `n` strings is `O(n + max{i}/k)`.

The one thing that makes this relevant to C... is that there's no built-in hash table, of course! So #2 may be easier to implement.

Comment: It's mentioned in the comments to the question, but not in your answer: at some point you'll want to extract the lines *in order* (otherwise, what's the point of the line numbers?), which isn't straightforward to do with a hash table.

Comment: The hash table described in my answer contains the pointer to the next line's value in the value, so traversing in order is easy. I see now how that could be unclear. When I say "pointer to next line's value," I mean the tuple for the next line, which in turn points to the tuple for the line after that... Not just the string of the next line. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: How do you maintain those pointers-to-the-next-line?  I'll assume you always keep a pointer to the last line, but that doesn't help much with inserting into the middle.  Either you iterate over the linked list to search for the insertion point (in which case, what is the point of using a hash table at all?) or you hope that the line numbers aren't spaced out by enormous amounts and successively guess what the previous line number is.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I somehow misread the OP a bunch of times and didn't see that he wanted to insert into the middle quickly, so I was only thinking about access. Editing... #1 is still faster to access, so it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume the following about your requirements:

1. **No strong real time.** (I.e. it's not for high frequency trading, or controlling machinery.)
2. It runs on a **relatively contemporary PC** (RAM measured in GB, CPU frequency in GHz). In particular it does not run on an embedded system.
3. The data is **no more than a few ten thousand lines.**

Then you can use almost any data structure you like; it won't matter with respect to memory or run time behavior.

For example, in order to find the point of insertion in a linked list, just iterate that list. PCs are fast enough to iterate tens of thousands of times before you finished blinking.

Or just allocate an array of 100,000 lines of 80 characters each. No problem whatsoever. Or of a million lines. Still no problem. Or of 10 million lines, still no problem. You see my point? (In an array you'll need a marker to mark unused lines. I would use a `struct line { bool used; char text[80]; }`  or the like. You can also cater to arbitrarily long lines — and save memory — by having just a `char *text` member and allocating dynamically, or defining the text as a linked list of chunks.)

The choice therefore boils down to *what's easiest for you to use.* Could be the array.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're looking for a specialized data structure, but how about instead using a *simple* data structure but sorting it *lazily*?  You could append new lines to a dynamic array and then sort the array (with `qsort`) when you need to print them.

I think that this would be better because printing all lines is probably done *much* less frequently than adding/inserting lines.  Therefore you should make adding lines cheap (in this case, O(1) amortized), and printing can be more expensive (in this case, O(*n* log *n*)).  This also keeps your data structures simple and lets the C standard library handle the complicated parts.

You could make this a bit better still by keeping a flag that tracks whether all of the data is already known to be sorted; that way repeatedly printing (or, presuming you're trying to write a BASIC interpreter, repeatedly running) will be cheap too.  Such a flag also might be helpful if you expect that lines are *usually* entered in order; then as each line is added:

```
alreadySorted = alreadySorted && (new_line_number > last_line_number)
```

I'll note that you have not specified what happens if a line is added that reuses an existing line number.  If you wish to replace the old line, then you could tweak this approach by using a *stable sort* and afterward iterating over the lines to remove lines with duplicate numbers, keeping only the last one.

(If you want to make `qsort` stable for this case, instead of storing just a string for each line, you could store some extra metadata with it (any monotonically increasing counter would do, such as the current time, or just the total number of lines at the time the line was added).  Then the comparison function you give to `qsort` would just need to use that extra data to resolve ties from duplicate line numbers.)

One disadvantage to this approach is that *removing* lines either won't be fast or won't reclaim memory immediately.  However, you haven't specified whether line removal is a requirement; even if it is, it is likely to be a rare operation (so being a bit more time-inefficient or a bit more space-inefficient might be acceptable).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this task is to use dictionary data type.
Of course, depending on nature of keys (number of lines) you can perform optimization via appropriate hash table.

Of course, c library don't have implementation of dictionary. But you can create your own, based on red black tree. Cormen explained such data structure easily [https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Note: if your collection has small size or you will rarely modify structure, then you can just use linked list.

Comment: ... which C doesn't have; do you have a suggestion for a library? Because implementing it ad-hoc would be overkill. (I googled and glib came up.)

Comment: Cormen  has great and simple implementation. See https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844

Comment: I think a red-black tree (or other balanced binary search tree) would be fine, but "an appropriate hash table" would have the problem that extracting the data in order is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use linked list and insertion sort to insert whenever needed ,

Here is the code modified on originally taken from geeksforgeeks.org,

I haven't tested code , this is just modified code as taken from the site.

```
 /* C program for insertion sort on a linked list */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int lineNumber;
    char *str;
    struct node* next;
}node;

// Function to insert a given node in a sorted linked list
void sortedInsert(struct node**, struct node*);

// function to sort a singly linked list using insertion sort
void insertionSort(struct node **head_ref)
{
    // Initialize sorted linked list
    struct node *sorted = NULL;

    // Traverse the given linked list and insert every
    // node to sorted
    struct node *current = *head_ref;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        // Store next for next iteration
        struct node *next = current->next;

        // insert current in sorted linked list
        sortedInsert(&sorted, current);

        // Update current
        current = next;
    }

    // Update head_ref to point to sorted linked list
    *head_ref = sorted;
}


/* function to insert a new_node in a list. Note that this
function expects a pointer to head_ref as this can modify the
head of the input linked list (similar to push())*/
void sortedInsert(struct node** head_ref, struct node* new_node)
{
    struct node* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head_ref == NULL || (*head_ref)->lineNumber >= new_node->lineNumber)
    {
        new_node->next = *head_ref;
        *head_ref = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *head_ref;
        while (current->next!=NULL &&
            current->next->lineNumber < new_node->lineNumber)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        new_node->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}

/* BELOW FUNCTIONS ARE JUST UTILITY TO TEST sortedInsert */

/* Function to print linked list */
void printList(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d  %s \n", temp->lineNumber,temp->str);

        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

/* A utility function to insert a node at the beginning of linked list */
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data, char *line)
{
    /* allocate node */
    struct node* new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int len = strlen(line)+1;
    /* put in the data */
    new_node->lineNumber = new_data;

    new_node->str = malloc(len);
    strcpy(new_node->str,line);
    new_node->str[len]  = '\0';

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}



// Driver program to test above functions
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    struct node *a = NULL;
    push(&a, 5 , "TestLine");
    push(&a, 1 , "SecondTest");
    push(&a, 1 , "SecondTest");
    push(&a, 3 , "SecondTest");
    insertionSort(&a);


    printf("\nLinked List after sorting \n");
    printList(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I' d advice you to use linked list.

```
// Define your list like this
typedef struct node {
    int line; // To hold the line number
    char * data;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

// To insert
node_t* insert(node_t *head, const char * data, int line) // n is line from beginning
{
    // Node to be inserted in given line
    node_t *newNode;

    // Allocating Memory
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    // Filling the Data to New Node
    newNode->data = malloc(strlen(data)+1); // Allocate memory to store data
    strcpy(newNode->data, data);
    newNode->line = line;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    // It might be our First Node in Linked List
    if(head == NULL) {

        //Address of New Node Becomes our head
        return (head = newNode);
    } 

    // Node Might be inserted At Head
    else if(line == 0) {
        // Joining previous Linked List After new Node
        newNode->next = head;

       // Address of New Node Becomes our head
        return (head = newNode);
    } 

    // Inserting At the line next to line
    else {

        // Pointer to store intermediate address of node
        // To be used in Traversing
        node_t * current = head;

        // Go through to insert at Nth line
        while(current != NULL) {

            node_t * next = current->next; //The next Node

            if((line >= current->line && line < next->line) || (line >= current->line && NULL == next->line)) { // Test if we are at some point between current line and next line or if there is no next

                // If we are, point newNode to the next node of current
                newNode->next = current->next;

                // Now point current towards our New Node
                current->next = newNode;

                // Return Head as soon as we have inserted our new node
                return head;
            }
            current = next; // Point current to the next node to continue
        }
    }
}
```

If there's guarantee that the line numbers will always be greater, you could also store a pointer to the node with greatest line number in every node. This will increase space but achieve the result in n(0) time.